# Guardar el valor de color de wp-color-picker en una opción de la base de datos en WordPress

Tags: php, base-de-datos, wordpress

Estoy creando una página de opciones para un plugin de WordPress, donde quiero colocar una opción donde el usuario pueda elegir un color en el **wp-color-picker** de WordPress, para guardarlo como opción en la base de datos y yo pueda usarlo después, que queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, el color-picker se inicia sin ningún problema y puedo seleccionar un color diferente. El problema viene cuando intento guardar la opción de color en la base de datos al presionar guardar cambios.

Al activar el plugin, guardo la opción con el siguiente código (donde la opción importante es color_scheme):

```js
$wprc_form_settings = array(
        'active_fields' => array( 'reason'=>1, 'reporter_name'=>1,'reporter_email'=>1,'details'=>1 ),
        'required_fields' => array( 'reason'=>1, 'reporter_name'=>1,'reporter_email'=>1,'details'=>1 ),
        'report_reasons' => "Spam\nContenido no válido\nContenido inadecuado",
        'slidedown_button_text' => 'Reportar',
        'submit_button_text' => 'Enviar',
        'color_scheme' => '#568541'
    );
  add_option( 'wprc_form_settings', $wprc_form_settings );
```

Y se registra en la página de opciones con este código:

```js
add_settings_section( 'form_settings_section', null, null, 'wprc_settings' );

add_settings_field(

        'color_scheme', '', 'wprc_render_settings_field', 'wprc_settings', 'form_settings_section',
        array(
            'title' => 'Tema de color',
            'desc' => 'Esquema de colores para el formulario',
            'id' => 'color_scheme',
            'class' => 'color_picker',
            'type' => 'text',
            'group' => 'wprc_form_settings'
        )
    );
    
    register_setting( 'wprc_settings', 'wprc_form_settings', 'wprc_settings_validation' );
```

Y se muestra en la página de opciones con este código :

```js
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $option_value[$args['id']]; ?>" class="<?php echo $args['class']; ?>" name="<?php echo $args['id']; ?>"/>
```

Cabe destacar que también registro otras opciones, pero no tengo problemas con ninguna otra, por eso no las coloco.

Sé que hasta aquí todo está funcionando bien porque al ingresar por primera vez a la página de opciones se muestra todo perfecto. Pero al hacer clic en Guardar Cambios, y verificar en la base de datos, se elimina la clave del array para **color_scheme** y por ende genera un error cuando intenta colocar el valor en la siguiente línea `value="<?php echo $option_value[$args['id']]; ?>"` porque el id **color_scheme** ya no existe en el array, no entiendo por qué se elimina al guardar las opciones.

No sé si tenga que ver con sanitizar la opción, pero todas las formas que he intentado con `sanitize_hex_color()` ninguna ha funcionado. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.